# Query database 1, find matching row and update into database 2

Tags: php, mariadb

I have 2 separate databases. Both contain a column called "UID". I need to scan each row in database 1 and 2 and if "UID" matches then update database 2 with the rest of the row's information. Please advise the best way to go about this in PHP. I do have code an so far testing fine but want to be sure this is the best way to go about it

```
//database 1 query 
$query_db1 = mysqli_query($conn_db1, "SELECT *
FROM `table`.`list`
WHERE `list`.`reg_date` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 24 HOUR)");

$counter = 0;
while ($row_db1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_db1)) {

  //find records, compare uid, if found then update status
  //prepare update query into database 2
  $stmt = $conn_db2->prepare("UPDATE TABLE SET Disposition=? WHERE UID=?");
  $stmt->bind_param("ss", $row_db1['status'], $row_db1['UID']);

    if ($stmt->execute()) {
    echo "success, "; 
    if($stmt->affected_rows === 1){
      $counter++;
      }

   } else {
        echo "Error connecting to database";
  }

}

echo "Rows updated: $counter <br>";

$stmt->close();
```

Comment: Are the two tables actually in separate _databases_, or are they in the same database?

Comment: 2 completely seperated databases on 2 different servers

Comment: Then this is as good as you can get, at least with using PHP.  If the two tables were on the same server, then my deleted answer might have helped you.

Comment: Great thanks for the response. So you agree the above code is correct? Just wanted to be sure before I start running this on my production server- don't want to mess up my database or corrupt any data

Comment: What you really would like to do here is an update join, all happing on a single MariaDB server.  You can't do that, because you have two separate servers, so manual iteration of the select result set seems like the only option here.

Comment: thanks and doing it with the while statement as per above is the best way? or would one rather use some sort of "if" or "foreach" statement? I assume my "UPDATE" query should be inside the "while" loop? and is $stmt->close(); in the correct place in my code- outside of the "While" loop?

Comment: The biggest performance bottleneck here are the large number of round trips you have to make for each separate update statement, not your PHP code.

Comment: I am indexing my "UID" column so the code takes under a second to execute on a database table containing around 400 000 rows. Also timing the script execution time with each run.

Comment: See the `CONNECT` and/or `FEDERATEDx` feature of MariaDB for allowing you to talk to two servers.